# How can I remove files from a Git repo in NetBeans?

Tags: git, netbeans

I have several project config files that got stuck in the tree when I initially commited in NetBeans, and now they refuse to be removed from the commit. How can I remove them from within NetBeans?

Comment: Do you want to ignore some files and remove ignored files that already committed?

Comment: If you're having trouble manipulating your git repo/files from netbeans and are averse to using the terminal, you could try a Git desktop client http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: @timoras - Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Nathan2055 Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

*If you just want to delete a file in a local repo, apply the first two steps only, but I assume you want to push the changes into a remote one too.*

**So here's how it goes:**

1. Open the *"Files"* or *"Projects"* window
2. Right click on the file(s), select *"Delete"*, then press *OK*.
3. In the *"Projects"* window, right-click the root node (*"Source Files"*), then  press *"Git"→"Commit"*
4. Approve the files to be deleted (they will be marked with yellow, and checked by default) then press *Commit*. You can optionally set the commit message too.
5. Repeat step 3, but this time select *"Git"→"Remote"→"Push to Upstream"*

And that's it, the file changes are now pushed into the remote side.